# How many iOS developers can work using the same iOS development license?

Tags: ios, licensing

Once a developer has signed up for an "individual iOS developer" license, can he add other developers to his team using the same license?

In other words, do I need to register as an iPhone developer and get another license to work with him?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: Also... it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your friend enrolled as an Individual, you will not be able to access his program. The only way you would have been able to join him is if he chose to register as a Company. Keep in mind, registering as a company does NOT mean you are automatically in the Enterprise program. The regular Developer Program allows you to create apps for distribution only through the App Store, wheras, the Enterprise allows you to distribute in-house applications without having to go through the App Store.

I'm not sure if he can convert his program from Individual to Company but if he can, that will still require quite a bit of effort like providing Apple with documentation for the business.

Pretty sure it'll end up being much cheaper and less of a pain if you get your own. The only problem is that if the app ends up being sold on the App Store, only one of your names will be identified as the seller. Also, if it is paid, only one of you will be able to collect the revenue for it (I may be wrong on that part, so anyone feel free to correct me).

Hope that helps and good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there’s no problem with multiple developers working under a single developer license. Just the obvious drawbacks like having just a single contact e-mail etc.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to confirm this? I'm looking at doing exactly this with a friend but don't want to buy an individual membership to find out that we can't share the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have registered as an individual iOS developer you cant add anyone.
You need to register as for a company if you want to add users inside a single developer license.